# How can i get/show the file size in real time?

Tags: c#, winforms, pipe

I have this code im using ffmpeg.exe to compress the file and then using pipstream write im getting a bitmap from Form1 timer each 40ms and write it to a pipestream .

When i close the application it's creating a new avi video file on the hard disk.

I want to get/show each time maybe each 40ms or each time a new bitmap was arrived the size of the file even if the file is not yet created on the hard disk i want to see in real time what the file size will be . for eample :

40kb then after 40ms 120kb then after 40ms 200kb and so on..

```
public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            string outPath = pathFileName;
            p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
            b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
            psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
            process = Process.Start(psi);
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            p.WaitForConnection();
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {

            int length;
            // Lock the bitmap's bits.
            //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
            // Get the address of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
            length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

            //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
            int j = bmp.Height - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
            {
                IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                j--;
            }
            p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);
            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once possibility would be to make ffmpeg write its output to stdout rather than to a file. Then you can capture the output by setting the [RedirectStandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) property.

It will then be up to you to read the redirected output and save it to disk yourself. Of course you'll then know exactly how much data you've saved as you're saving it.